# JPA Join on conditional result in N+1 problem

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am facing with multiple select queries (N+1) to JOIN.ON conditional. Here is my example

Here is my mapping in **Person** entity

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleId", referencedColumnName = "vehicleId")
    })
    @WhereJoinTable( clause = "vehicle_color = 'RED' " ) - I did try this annotation but dont see conditional join in hibernate generated query
    private Vehicle vehicle;
```

so I tried using CriteriaBuilder

```
Join<Person, Car> vehicleJoin = personJoin.join("vehicle", JoinType.LEFT);
vehicleJoin.on(criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(personJoin.get(" vehicle_color = 'RED' ")))
```

As soon as I added vehicleJoin.on criteria, I did see it joined properly but it is executing a select query for each Car for that Person

I want to avoid multiple selects and fetch all vehicles data as part main Query

Here are jars using in my Project

> spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.1.6
>
> Hibernate-core 5.3.10

Thank you for your inputs in advance. Hoping it is easier to read and understand :D

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are writing an entity query? This is not really possible as you'd have to use a fetch join with an ON condition. Since that will alter the persistent state of the collection, which might lead to unexpected deletes, it is disallowed in JPA.

You need a tuple query instead i.e. a custom projection.

This is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

A sample model could look like the following:

```
@EntityView(Person.class)
public interface PersonView {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    @Mapping("vehicle[color = 'RED']")
    VehicleView getVehicle();
}
@EntityView(Vehicle.class)
public interface VehicleView {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    String getName();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`PersonView p = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, PersonView.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features i.e. have a repository similar to the following

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository {
    PersonView findById(Integer id);
}
```